# Attribute Routing in Web API with RoutePrefix - Strange error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

```
    [RoutePrefix("ServiceRequest")]
    public class ServiceRequestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]ServiceRequest.Models.ServiceRequest serviceRequest)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

I use an empty `Route()` for a `POST` in `WebAPI` and invoke

`http://localhost.com:59985/ServiceRequest/

This throws an error stating `HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed` and most likely causes given were

- The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP verb that is not
  allowed by the module configured to handle the request

  (or)

  A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid HTTP verb

  (or)

  The request is for static content and contains an HTTP verb other
  than GET or HEAD

  (or)

  A request was sent to a virtual directory using the HTTP verb POST
  and the default document is a static file that does not support HTTP
  verbs other than GET or HEAD.

However if use Route("Test"), the method `just works fine` as like below:

[POST] to http://localhost.com:59985/ServiceRequest/Test -- works fine. `(Route is [Route("Test")])`

[POST] to http://localhost.com:59985/ServiceRequest ------- does not work `(Route is [Route("")]`

Is empty `Route` not allowed for POST ?
Any ideas what is wrong here ?

Comment: For the 405 response, what values do you see in the "Allow" header?

Comment: @KiranChalla: Please see the below answer. Turned out to be that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be some issue because the `[RoutePrefix("ServiceRequest")]` had the same name as the controller name.

When I changed the `[RoutePrefix()]` everything worked fine as before.

Comment: What did you change `[RoutePrefix()]` to?  It doesn't have an public empty constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`[RoutePrefix]` adds a prefix to your routes. So, in your example, if you don't specify the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute, then by convention your route would be:

```
.../api/ServiceRequest
```

By adding the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute you are saying that the routes in this controller will be prefixed by the specified route, i.e. you are effectively changing your route to:

```
.../api/ServiceRequest/ServiceRequest
```

Could this be the reason for your issue? I'm not sure having a `RoutePrefix` with the same name as the controller was necessarily the problem, but I could be wrong -- I'm still pretty new at this stuff.

Comment: I guess not the same.. Whenever you use `attribute routing`, you dont need to use `../api/..` at all. It replaces them and defines a new route internally